# What to do if /usr/lib/python*/site-packages is accidentally deleted?

Tags: python, centos7

I have accidentally deleted my `site-packages` folder for python2.7.5 under `/usr/lib/` .

If have seen that if this problem happens i need to install python again.

So, i took an rpm and tried `rpm -i python*`

But, it says i have already installed python2.7.5 in my centOS 7.

I kind of got stuck, how to resolve this?

N.B. I have no Internet connection on that centOS 7.

Comment: if you try to install python, os get newest. if you have a lot of python application, need install every module from source. scan open directories (on web) copy all basic library. your additional sorce maybe can't found on web.

Comment: Basically it was a vm in centOS7, what i have done is copying the whole site-package directory from another vm of same network, that has solved my problem.

Comment: It's not exactly. even an extra programs which module requires? collect errors get source, install manually. (don't forget file permissions)

Comment: Uninstall it and then reinstall it.